# How to compare an object against an array of objects where positions of some values won't be the same

Tags: javascript, zapier

Please note that I am still a beginner in Javascript, any feedback on my logic below would be appreciated.

(This code is being written for Zapier) I am trying to create a search feature to find a contact in a list of contacts.
Static information is mobile, first name and last name. Then the list can contain up to 10 custom fields (that can be named anything the user wants). When making the API call to return the information, the custom field names are stored in a "fields" object, with key/vale pairs of field_n = "Name". The values are then use in the recipients object where the contact information is stored.

I was thinking the easiest way would be to create an object that would store the information the user is searching by:

```
var dataEntered = {
    "mobile" : ,
    "firstName" : ,
    "lastName" : ,
    "custom1" : ,
    "custom2" : ,
    "custom3" : ,
    "custom4" : ,
    "custom5" : ,
    "custom6" : ,
    "custom7" : ,
    "custom8" : ,
    "custom9" : ,
    "custom10" : 
};

function checkData () {
    if (mobile !== null) dataEntered.mobile = mobile;
    if (firstName !== null) dataEntered.firstName = firstName;
    if (lastName !== null) dataEntered.lastName = lastName;
    if (custom1 !== null) dataEntered.custom1 = custom1;
    if (custom2 !== null) dataEntered.custom2 = custom2;
    if (custom3 !== null) dataEntered.custom3 = custom3;
    if (custom4 !== null) dataEntered.custom4 = custom4;
    if (custom5 !== null) dataEntered.custom5 = custom5;
    if (custom6 !== null) dataEntered.custom6 = custom6;
    if (custom7 !== null) dataEntered.custom7 = custom7;
    if (custom8 !== null) dataEntered.custom8 = custom8;
    if (custom9 !== null) dataEntered.custom9 = custom9;
    if (custom10 !== null) dataEntered.custom10 = custom10;
};
```

Then loop through the list and assign it to an array of objects:

```
var listData = [{
    "mobile" : ,
    "firstName" : ,
    "lastName" : ,
    "custom1" : ,
    "custom2" : ,
    "custom3" : ,
    "custom4" : ,
    "custom5" : ,
    "custom6" : ,
    "custom7" : ,
    "custom8" : ,
    "custom9" : ,
    "custom10" : 
}];

for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    listData[i].mobile = contacts[i].msisdn;
    listData[i].firstName = contacts[i].first_name;
    listData[i].lastName = contacts[i].last_name;
    if (contacts[i][obj.fields.field_1] !== undefined) listData[i].custom1 = contacts[i][obj.fields.field_1];
    if (contacts[i][obj.fields.field_2] !== undefined) listData[i].custom1 = contacts[i][obj.fields.field_2];
    if (contacts[i][obj.fields.field_3] !== undefined) listData[i].custom1 = contacts[i][obj.fields.field_3];
    if (contacts[i][obj.fields.field_4] !== undefined) listData[i].custom1 = contacts[i][obj.fields.field_4];
    if (contacts[i][obj.fields.field_5] !== undefined) listData[i].custom1 = contacts[i][obj.fields.field_5];
    if (contacts[i][obj.fields.field_6] !== undefined) listData[i].custom1 = contacts[i][obj.fields.field_6];
    if (contacts[i][obj.fields.field_7] !== undefined) listData[i].custom1 = contacts[i][obj.fields.field_7];
    if (contacts[i][obj.fields.field_8] !== undefined) listData[i].custom1 = contacts[i][obj.fields.field_8];
    if (contacts[i][obj.fields.field_9] !== undefined) listData[i].custom1 = contacts[i][obj.fields.field_9];
    if (contacts[i][obj.fields.field_10] !== undefined) listData[i].custom1 = contacts[i][obj.fields.field_10];
}
```

However, where i'm stuck is that the custom data in the list, may not match the order of how the user enters it.

From doing some research it appears the easiest way to return a match is if the two objects have the key/values to compare in the same order.

Am I on the right track for the best way to do this?

Full Code (so far)

```
find_list_post_search: function(bundle) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(bundle.response.content)[
    var contacts = obj.recipients;
    var mobile = bundle.search_fields.contact_number;
    var firstName = bundle.search_fields.first_name;
    var lastName = bundle.search_fields.last_name;
    var custom1 = bundle.search_fields.custom_field1;
    var custom2 = bundle.search_fields.custom_field2;
    var custom3 = bundle.search_fields.custom_field3;
    var custom4 = bundle.search_fields.custom_field4;
    var custom5 = bundle.search_fields.custom_field5;
    var custom6 = bundle.search_fields.custom_field6;
    var custom7 = bundle.search_fields.custom_field7;
    var custom8 = bundle.search_fields.custom_field8;
    var custom9 = bundle.search_fields.custom_field9;
    var custom10 = bundle.search_fields.custom_field10;

var dataEntered = {
    "mobile" : ,
    "firstName" : ,
    "lastName" : ,
    "custom1" : ,
    "custom2" : ,
    "custom3" : ,
    "custom4" : ,
    "custom5" : ,
    "custom6" : ,
    "custom7" : ,
    "custom8" : ,
    "custom9" : ,
    "custom10" : 
};

var fields = {
    "field_1" : ,
    "field_2" : ,
    "field_3" : ,
    "field_4" : ,
    "field_5" : ,
    "field_6" : ,
    "field_7" : ,
    "field_8" : ,
    "field_9" : ,
    "field_10" : 
};

var listData = [{
    "mobile" : ,
    "firstName" : ,
    "lastName" : ,
    "custom1" : ,
    "custom2" : ,
    "custom3" : ,
    "custom4" : ,
    "custom5" : ,
    "custom6" : ,
    "custom7" : ,
    "custom8" : ,
    "custom9" : ,
    "custom10" : 
}];

function checkFields () {
    if (obj.fields !== undefined) {
        if (obj.fields.field_1 !== null) fields.field_1 = obj.fields.field_1;
        if (obj.fields.field_2 !== null) fields.field_2 = obj.fields.field_2;
        if (obj.fields.field_3 !== null) fields.field_3 = obj.fields.field_3;
        if (obj.fields.field_4 !== null) fields.field_4 = obj.fields.field_4;
        if (obj.fields.field_5 !== null) fields.field_5 = obj.fields.field_5;
        if (obj.fields.field_6 !== null) fields.field_6 = obj.fields.field_6;
        if (obj.fields.field_7 !== null) fields.field_7 = obj.fields.field_7;
        if (obj.fields.field_8 !== null) fields.field_8 = obj.fields.field_8;
        if (obj.fields.field_9 !== null) fields.field_9 = obj.fields.field_9;
        if (obj.fields.field_10 !== null) fields.field_10 = obj.fields.field_10;
    }
}

function checkData () {
    if (mobile !== null) dataEntered.mobile = mobile;
    if (firstName !== null) dataEntered.firstName = firstName;
    if (lastName !== null) dataEntered.lastName = lastName;
    if (custom1 !== null) dataEntered.custom1 = custom1;
    if (custom2 !== null) dataEntered.custom2 = custom2;
    if (custom3 !== null) dataEntered.custom3 = custom3;
    if (custom4 !== null) dataEntered.custom4 = custom4;
    if (custom5 !== null) dataEntered.custom5 = custom5;
    if (custom6 !== null) dataEntered.custom6 = custom6;
    if (custom7 !== null) dataEntered.custom7 = custom7;
    if (custom8 !== null) dataEntered.custom8 = custom8;
    if (custom9 !== null) dataEntered.custom9 = custom9;
    if (custom10 !== null) dataEntered.custom10 = custom10;
};

checkFields();
checkData();

for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    listData[i].mobile = contacts[i].msisdn;
    listData[i].firstName = contacts[i].first_name;
    listData[i].lastName = contacts[i].last_name;
    if (contacts[i][obj.fields.field_1] !== undefined) listData[i].custom1 = contacts[i][obj.fields.field_1];
    if (contacts[i][obj.fields.field_2] !== undefined) listData[i].custom1 = contacts[i][obj.fields.field_2];
    if (contacts[i][obj.fields.field_3] !== undefined) listData[i].custom1 = contacts[i][obj.fields.field_3];
    if (contacts[i][obj.fields.field_4] !== undefined) listData[i].custom1 = contacts[i][obj.fields.field_4];
    if (contacts[i][obj.fields.field_5] !== undefined) listData[i].custom1 = contacts[i][obj.fields.field_5];
    if (contacts[i][obj.fields.field_6] !== undefined) listData[i].custom1 = contacts[i][obj.fields.field_6];
    if (contacts[i][obj.fields.field_7] !== undefined) listData[i].custom1 = contacts[i][obj.fields.field_7];
    if (contacts[i][obj.fields.field_8] !== undefined) listData[i].custom1 = contacts[i][obj.fields.field_8];
    if (contacts[i][obj.fields.field_9] !== undefined) listData[i].custom1 = contacts[i][obj.fields.field_9];
    if (contacts[i][obj.fields.field_10] !== undefined) listData[i].custom1 = contacts[i][obj.fields.field_10];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you should really use a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) data structure to do this. then you can just iterate through the fields and set them (see the link for examples on how to initialize and add data to a map.)

```
var map = new Map();

for(var i < 0; i < map.length; i++)
{
   map["custom" + "i"] = bundle.search_fields["custom_field" + i.toString()];
}
//you can add the other fields here too.
```